# Miscellaneous confusion about Xcode build settings (64/32 bits, SDK version, etc)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, ide

When I create a new OS X application project, I noticed many target options those confuse me quite a lot:

---

**(1) The top-left setting of Xcode window:**
[image: Top-left]

---

**(2) The "Base SDK":**
[image: Base SDK]

---

**(3) "Deployment Target":** 
[image: Deployment Target]

---

**(4) Architectures:**
[image: Architectures]

---

Here comes **my questions**:

For (2) and (3), I think it was clearer to understand. These are what I comprehend:
(2) This identifies what I develop with.
(3) This identifies what OS version my application will be used on.
**Please tell me whether I am right...**

But I could not understand (1). I just know that if I select 32-bit here, I could not use ARC.

Neither with (4), what are they? Are they represent the bit-width of the CPU? What was the difference between (1) and (4)?

Comment: 1. is the deployment target, 4. is the compilation target.

Comment: 1+3: deployment issue; 2+4: development issue. Am I right? But What is the difference between 32-it, 64-bit, 32/64-bit in (4) while there are only two options in (1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll explain your items out of order.

#### The Base SDK

This defines the largest set of APIs you can use. You can use anything that existed as of the version number identified here. For example, if you use the 10.8 SDK, you can use `-[NSColor CGColor]` (introduced in 10.8), but not `-[NSData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:]` (first public in 10.9).

(Of course, you can also use anything older than that version.)

Accordingly, the SDK version is also known as the “max[imum] allowed” version in the Availability macros.

The SDK version also sometimes becomes important when Apple changes the behavior of an API. When they do that, they sometimes keep the old behavior around for applications linked with older SDKs. This is called an “on-or-after check”, as in “checks whether you're on 10.8 [SDK] or later”. (The concept and term pre-date Xcode having SDKs for each OS version. It used to just go by whatever OS you were running Xcode and building on.)

#### The Deployment Target

This is the *minimum* OS version you require. If something was removed in a prior version (rare, but it happens), you can't use it.

This tends to affect link-time and run-time things more than compile-time things. For example, ARC won't work if your deployment target is 10.5 or earlier.

Accordingly, the Deployment Target is also known as the “min[imum] required” version in the Availability macros.

The Info.plist can also specify a minimum OS version. Nowadays, this is set by default and it's set by macro expansion to the Deployment Target.

#### The Architectures build setting

Different CPUs have different architectures. Essentially, they fit into broad categories, such as:

- PowerPC 32-bit (`ppc`)
- PowerPC 64-bit (`ppc64`)
- Intel 32-bit (`i386`)
- Intel 64-bit (`x86_64`)
- ARM 32-bit
- ARM 64-bit

(PowerPC architectures aren't supported anymore. You can add them to the Architectures list, as `ppc` and `ppc64`, but Xcode will just ignore them.)

Macs nowadays have Intel processors. Almost all Intel Macs have 64-bit processors. You only need to worry about 32-bit Intel if you want to support Macs all the way back to 2006. That's probably more hassle than it's worth.

iOS devices run ARM processors, and most are still 32-bit. The A7 (iPhone 5S, iPad Air, iPad Mini with Retina Display) is 64-bit. But, if you run on an iOS Simulator, it's running on your Mac (it's a Simulator, not an emulator), so it'll target an Intel architecture (formerly always `i386`, but probably can now be `x86_64` if needed).

#### The “top-left setting of Xcode window”

This is the build scheme and run destination. (Yes, it's two separate things in one pop-up menu. Actually, it's two separate pop-up menus in one control. Try it.)

“My Mac 64-bit” is the run destination. You'll be running the 64-bit version of your app on your Mac, not in an iOS Simulator or on an iOS device. Your choice for a Mac app is merely which architecture you want to run, and they *should* behave the same (this is, obviously, something you sometimes need to test).

iOS apps have more choices here. Some apps are iPhone-only, some are iPad-only, some are universal, and some may be set to build for both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. You'll have a Simulator offered for each combination of form factor and architecture (e.g., iPhone Simulator 64-bit) you can run on. You'll *also* have the option to run your app on any iOS device that's connected and enabled for development (you get this prompt when you plug in the device in Xcode's sight).

#### TL;DR

- Deployment Target is the lowest OS version your app will run on.
- Base SDK is the highest OS version you can use stuff from. If it didn't exist yet, it doesn't exist at all for you.
- Architectures are the set of hardware your app will run on.
- Run Destination is the hardware *you're* going to run it on from within Xcode.

Comment: As to CPU, there are 32-bit and 64-bit type, while also to OSes (for example, Win 7 x86, Win 7 x64). What you mentioned was the bit-width of CPU architecture, but how about OS X? Are there OS X x86 and OS X x64?

Comment: @AndrewChang: I don't know where Windows comes into this; we're talking about Xcode, which (AFAIK) can't be used to make Windows software. There is only one distribution of OS X, which runs on both architectures (for a time, it even ran on all four: both PowerPC + both Intel). Your only choice of OS is whether a target builds for OS X or iOS. If you're building for OS X, you can build your app for i386 and/or x86_64, and you can run on any architecture you're building for at will. The same goes for iOS and the various supported ARM architectures.

Comment: I checked with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard), it said: "Snow Leopard is the last release of Mac OS X to support the 32-bit Intel Core Solo and Intel Core Duo CPUs." So it may be a "yes, there are OS X with 32-bit and 64-bit mode". But since 10.6 is the last supporting 32-bit CPUes, and my deployment target is 10.7, I need no concern about 32-bit. In short, THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!

Answer (score 3):

Just like with most OSes these days you can develop either a 32bit or a 64bit application. The "bitness" refers mostly to how memory addresses are structured (either using 32bit allowing so at most 4GB to address or 64bit (computation left as an exercise to the reader)). However the choosen architecture usually has more implications (like the missing ARC support for 32bit apps) but also how wide CPU registers are, how much memory a structure uses in RAM etc.

OS X also supports socalled **fat binaryies** that is, a bundle containing both 32bit and 64bit variants of your application. This is however only needed if you normally prefer to run 64bit code, but want your app also to run on OS versions that only support 32bit.

In XCode you can define for what architecture to build your project, either 32bit only, 64bit only or a fat bundle. In the project settings you can set what is allowed and in the top bar in XCode you can quickly switch between the allowed architectures (your questions 1 and 4).

The base SDK determines what you want to use to **compile** your application. If you select for instance 10.7 you cannot use new APIs that were introduced in 10.8 or 10.9 (which might perfectly be ok if you want your application to run on earlier OS versions only). However if you want to dynamically use new features if they are availble you'd select the latest OS as base SDK and **check in code** what OS you are running on and only use new features if they are available. It is totally ok to compile an application with access to new features and run it on older systems if you don't use the new APIs there (they are late-bound and hence only crash when you access them the first time and they are not available).

The deployment target determines the minimum OS version your application needs to run properly. This is a **runtime check** done when the application is started. The OS will refuse to start an application that is made for a later version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped a lot! But Peter's answer fits my question more.